# Меню с набором табов из TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть `TabControl`, который заполняется из коллекции`<MyClass>`. Я хочу сделать меню на случай, когда табы не вмещаются в панель. Есть такой код

```
<Menu Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1">
    <MenuItem Header="?"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>

            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Меню все отображает, но для возможности выбора таба из меню нужно еще кое что добавить. А именно

```
<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Проблема в том, что `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"` передает в меню коллекцию`<MyClass>`, а не `<TabItem>`, поэтому я не имею доступа к свойству `TabItem.IsSelected`. Можно ли это как то обойти?

Пока в голову приходит создать MultiBinding и передавать в конвертер сам TabControl и нужный экземпляр класса MyClass, а там уже получать TabItem при помощи `ItemContainerGenerator`. Но мне это решение не нравится. Есть ли более изящное?

**UPD:**

Сам класс, который отвечает за открытые вкладки, не имеет отношения к стартовому окну, поэтому я от него отказался в пользу обработчика `Application_Startup`. То есть именно там я сообщаю, что мне нужно открыть вкладку. Класс уже создает окно нужного типа (по умолчанию Window), добавляет в него MyTabControl в качестве контента и создает нужные биндинги В КОДЕ. Каждое окно соответствует группе `MyGroup`. Коллекцию табов `ObservableCollection<MyTab>` хранит в себе именно група. `MyTabControl.ItemsSource` биндится к этой `ObservableCollection`. Поэтому я в данный момент не вижу способа, как использовать предложенные в ответах варианты :(

Comment: Сделайте в своей `VM` поле `SelectedItem` и биндите его к `TabControl`, а при клике по меню присваивайте `SelectedItem` нужный элмента коллекции `Items`

Comment: @Donil, мне стыдно, но я не знаю, что такое в моем коде `ViewModel`. Уверен, что она есть, но у меня не очень с названиями :)

Comment: Не понятно почему мой вариант не подходит? Что не так?

Comment: Поменяйте Ваш **сеттер IsChecked** на мой.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Я пробовал. Я не понял, что нужно передать в первом биндинге. Точнее откуда мне это значение достать.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, мне нравится ваше решение. Я понимаю его смысл, но реализовать в моем случае не получается.

Comment: Если биндинг находится в стиле MenuItem, то пишите как у меня и написано, только **ElementName="f_TabControl"** поменяйте на **ElementName="Имя_Вашего_Таб_Контрола"**

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, у меня все это находится внутри класса MyTabControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:WpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Content>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Tabs..." ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=f_TabControl}">
          <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
              <EventSetter Event="MenuItem.Click" Handler="TabItemClick"/>
              <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                      <WpfApplication1:EqualsObjectsConverter/>
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext"/>
                      <Binding ElementName="f_TabControl" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                  </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
          </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      <TabControl Name="f_TabControl" Grid.Row="1"></TabControl>
    </Grid>
  </Window.Content>
</Window>
```

cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    protected List<String> m_Items = new List<string>(new String[]{"one", "twoo","three"});
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      f_TabControl.ItemsSource = m_Items; 
    }
    protected void TabItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      f_TabControl.SelectedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
    }
  }

  public class EqualsObjectsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; ++i)
        if (values[0] is IEnumerable<byte> && values[i] is IEnumerable<byte>)
        {
          if (!((IEnumerable<byte>)values[0]).SequenceEqual((IEnumerable<byte>)values[i]))
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
          if (!object.Equals(values[0], values[i]))
            return false;
        }
      return true;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
  }

}
```

UPD: описание алгоритма.

Алгоритм кода: ItemsSource табконтрола будет лист абстракций(в конкретном примере String), при клике на айтем меню выбирается соответствующий таб.

Алгоритм xaml'а:

Тут все немного посложнее...

Начнем с того, что айтемы меню дублируются из ItemsSource табконтрола ({Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=f_TabControl}).
Присваиваем событие клика в каждом подменю (итемов меню соответствующим табу табконтрола). А чекед итема будет в **True** только в том случае ItemsSource меню будет совпадать с активным табом в твбконтроле, за что и отвечает мультибиндинг **EqualsObjectsConverter**. Все, я кончил. пинайте.

Comment: естественно у Вас **List<String>** будет **List<MyClass>**

Comment: Спасибо, это решение, конечно, но я писал в вопросе "*Пока в голову приходит создать MultiBinding и передавать в конвертер сам TabControl и нужный экземпляр класса MyClass, а там уже получать TabItem при помощи ItemContainerGenerator. Но мне это решение не нравится. Есть ли более изящное?*". Если не будет других решений, отмечу как ответ. Тут иная реализация, но все равно грубовато.

Comment: пожалуй это самое изящное решение, которое я могу предложить :), а **EqualsObjectsConverter** может помочь Вам в будущем.

Comment: Хм... А как быть с  `Mode=TwoWay`?

Comment: а он тут и не нужен! Идет сравнение в **EqualsObjectsConverter**.

Comment: Ну так конвертер в любом случае возвращает какое то значение, которое определяет свойство `IsChecked`. А как мне при выборе элемента в меню добиться выделения выбранного таба?

Comment: Похоже я не совсем догоняю сути работы этого кода (

Comment: "А как мне при выборе элемента в меню добиться выделения выбранного таба?" при клике глянте

Comment: А что если названия табов будут одинаковыми?

Comment: У Вас объекты а не стринги! они не будут одинаковы в Вашем случае

Comment: Сейчас попробую. А можете пока описать в ответе суть работы этого конвертера? А то у меня не хватает оперативной памяти в голове чтобы это переварить? :)

Comment: У меня все иначе. Скоро добавлю к вопросу свою структуру. Может, поможете преобразовать ее и сделать похожей на вашу, пока что не вижу как это сделать (

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Ах да, я отказался от `IsChecked`. Не нравится мне то, что в меню нет свойства `CheckedItem` или типа того. Оказалось проще сделать событие на клик без связки. Мне не обязательно видеть в открытом меню, какая вкладка активна.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу вариант решения в стиле MVVM. Возможно, он вам больше понравится.

Для этого понадобятся модели представления вкладок и главного окна:

```
// Базовая модель представления (VM) вкладки. Нужна для обобщения алгоритма работы с вкладками.
public abstract class TabVm : ViewModel
{
    // VM родительского окна. Нужна для управления выбранной вкладкой
    protected MainWindowVm Parent { get; private set; }

    // Заголовок вкладки
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // Команда для открытия вкладки из меню
    public ICommand OpenFromMenu { get; private set; }

    public TabVm(MainWindowVm parent, string title)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Title = title;

        OpenFromMenu = new RelayCommand(_ => Parent.SelectedTab = this);
    }
}

// VM главного окна
public class MainWindowVm : ViewModel
{
    // Перечень вкладок
    public ObservableCollection<TabVm> Tabs
    {
        get { return _tabs ?? (_tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabVm>()); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<TabVm> _tabs;

    // Выбранная вкладка
    public TabVm SelectedTab
    {
        get { return _selectedTab; }
        set { SetField(ref _selectedTab, value); }
    }
    private TabVm _selectedTab;

    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        Tabs.Add(new Tab1Vm(this, "Tab1") { Content = "Content" });
        Tabs.Add(new Tab2Vm(this, "Tab2") { Text = "Text" });

        SelectedTab = Tabs.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

// Наследники базовой вкладки со своим содержимым
public class Tab1Vm : TabVm
{
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Tab1Vm(MainWindowVm parent, string title)
        : base(parent, title)
    {
    }
}
public class Tab2Vm : TabVm
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Tab2Vm(MainWindowVm parent, string title)
        : base(parent, title)
    {
    }
}
```

Класс `ViewModel` в данном случае представляет собой реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Примерно так, как это описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist). Реализацию `ICommand` (`RelayCommand`) можно подсмотреть [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example).

Теперь нужно представление главного окна:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Шаблоны можно подтянуть из отдельных файлов с ресурсами -->
        <!-- Шаблон содержимого первой вкладки -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab1Vm}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- Шаблон содержимого второй вкладки -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab2Vm}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="Tabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
                <MenuItem.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding OpenFromMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Resources>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так

```
<MenuItem.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="TabMenuItem_Click"/>
    </Style>
</MenuItem.Resources>
```

Обработчик:

```
private void TabMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mi = sender as MenuItem;
    if (mi != null)
    {
        var tab = mi.DataContext as MyTab;
        if (tab != null)
            SelectedItem = tab;
    }
}
```

Это все внутри MyTabControl

Comment: а чем Вам `f_TabControl.SelectedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;` не понравился?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, ценное замечание, поправил )